# SoftLayer: Order Bandwidth Package

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How do I add a bandwidth package to a new server order? Question pertains to virtual_guest and hardware "createObject" methods; neither of their 'getCreateObjectOptions' methods return options for bandwidth packages.

Answer (score 0):

The [SoftLayer_Hardware::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/createObject) and [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) methods are a simplified way to order servers, so they have the most common items to place an order. Unfortunately it's not possible to set the "bandwidth" using these methods.

However, you can order a server using "createObject" method, after the server has been provisioned, you can place an upgrade for the bandwith. Otherwise you can use [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method, it provides all available options at the moment to place an order.