# Can I specify bandwidth to soft layer API for creating a virtual server?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a virtual server through soft layer API. But the API I came across don't seem to accept network bandwidth, can't I specify the required bandwidth for my virtual server created through API?

Thanks,
Kishore

Comment: Take a look this forum please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045824/softlayer-order-bandwidth-package/36047448#36047448

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here an example using [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method to place an order for VSI with bandwidth:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "location":449494,
         "packageId":46,
         "hardware":[  
            {  
               "domain":"softlayer.com",
               "hostname":"test"
            }
         ],
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":1640
            },
            {  
               "id":1644
            },
            {  
               "id":13940
            },
            {  
               "id":2202
            },
            {  
               "id":50241
            },
            {  
               "id":273
            },
            {  
               "id":2302
            },
            {  
               "id":55
            },
            {  
               "id":58
            },
            {  
               "id":420
            },
            {  
               "id":418
            },
            {  
               "id":21
            },
            {  
               "id":57
            },
            {  
               "id":905
            },
            {  
               "id":14022
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The "50241" price refers to "5000 GB Bandwidth"

To retrieve information about item prices, try this:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices

Method: Get
```

References:

[SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)

Comment: Hi Ruber, Thanks for the reply. I have tried placeOrder API with the above input, but it says "Price #50241 doesn't exist", not only for this but for all the ids. I also ran the getItemPrices(), and the output doesn't contain these IDs at all.   I have instead tried to use the IDs returned by the getItemPrices() with the placeOrder call, but it complains the same for them too.  Is there anything wrong I am doing?  I just called POST methon on "https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder" with the above input.

Comment: If you are using [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices) method, it supposed that it should work fine, can you share the prices that you are trying? I will try to assist you with them.