# Softlayer rest api, pass bandwidth allocation parameter with the virtual server creation call

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What i am trying to do here is to set bandwidth allocation on an virtual server during the virtual server creation call. For example 250 GB, 500 GB etc total traffic allowed on the VM. And i am trying to achieve this by REST API. 
These are the parameters we are currently passing

```
{
    "parameters":[
        {
            "hostname": "",
            "domain": "",
            "datacenter": {
            "name": ""
        },
            "startCpus": '',
            "maxMemory": '',
            "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
        "blockDevices": [
        {
            "device": "0",
            "diskImage": {
            "capacity": ''
        }
        }
        ],
        "localDiskFlag": false,
        "networkComponents": [
        {
        "maxSpeed": 10
        }
        ],
        "softwareComponents": [
        {
        "id": 28
        }
        ],
        "operatingSystemReferenceCode": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set bandwidth allocation using [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) method. This method provide a simply way to order a VSI, to see the available options you can use this method:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getCreateObjectOptions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions)

Note: The Monthly Vsi's will be ordered with 250 GB Public Bandwidth and Hourly Vsi's with 0 GB Public Bandwidth

If you wish to set bandwidth or get more options at the moment to place an order for VSIs, you should use this method (It provides the full options that [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com) displays):

- [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder)

Here an example using REST:

- [Can I specify bandwidth to soft layer API for creating a virtual
  server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940436/can-i-specify-bandwidth-to-soft-layer-api-for-creating-a-virtual-server)